# The method println(boolean) in the type Printwriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, arguments

I want to call a method from my class but I think I messed something up with the declaration.

It says

> " The method println(boolean) in the type Printwriter is not
>   applicable for the arguments (void)"

Here is a part of my class

```
String Name = request.getParamter("name");  
Printwriter = p=response.getWriter();
Names n = new Names();
n.setName(Name);
p.println(Names.theName());
```

And here is my other class

```
... (getter and setter for Name) ...
public void theName(){ if(Name.equals("Josh"){ System.out.println("Hi Josh, what's up?")}
if(Name.equals("Peter"){System.out.printlkn("Hi Peter, how are you?")}
}
```

Comment: is your 2nd code snippet compilable?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether you pasted the actual code or typed it in - The errors I see in the code are mostly typos like:

```
String Name = request.getParamter("name");
```

Should correct the spell for Parameter

```
Printwriter = p=response.getWriter();
```

There are 2 "=" signs which is probably the issue

Comment: ups, no, it's just a typo over here.
I've got it right in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Your getter (`theName()`) needs to return a String instead of printing it out to stdout. Or in other words, the print writers println does not expect your getters return type (which is `void`)

Comment: so should I change the return type of my method ? To what should I change it ? I've tried string but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty clear.

> The method println(boolean) in the type Printwriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)

This basically means that the method you are executing `p.println(void)` is not accepting the `void` argument. You are passing a `void` there because your method `theName()` is a void method. You may want to return a `String` there.

Plese look at the `PrintWriter` documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html where you will see that there is no single method `println()` that accepts a void argument.

Updated method:

```
public void theName(){ 
    if(Name.equals("Josh")){
        return "Hi Josh, what's up?";
    }
    if(Name.equals("Peter")){
        return "Hi Peter, how are you?";
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have to change the return type of my method ? I've tried String but it didn't work. Any advice?

Comment: How does it not work? Update your code and show us what you have edited.

Comment: instead of having a void in front of the methd I wrote String but it still didn't work

Comment: You do also need to return a String. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your method:

```
public void theName(){...}
```

you cannot

```
p.println(Names.theName());
```

Use getter from the Names class instead to acces your name attribute.

Comment: But I want to have the System.out.println() of the method as result. If I would just use the getters I wouldn't get the result